# Why the method ImageIcon.getIconWidth() returns me the wrong size image on the first call?

Tags: java, awt, imageicon

The method returns me the wrong value (800) before I return the right value (140):

```
    public static ImageIcon loadImage(String name) {
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon(DIR_IMG + name);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(ic.getIconWidth() + " " + (ic.getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE));
        }

        return ic;
    }
```

The console prints:

```
800 true
800 true
800 true
140 true
140 true
```

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. I just created a class with a main method with the first line of code and the loop and all values output have the same correct width.

Comment: Do you load a PNG or JPG file?

Comment: Just tried jpg, png and gif and they all worked.